# KafkaStreams application reprocessing from start after broker failures

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a 3-broker Docker Kafka AWS cluster, and a 3-container KafkaStreams application processing from an "events" topic with replication=2.

I had the failure written by other user in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46644764/kafka-cached-zkversion-not-equal-to-that-in-zookeeper-broker-not-recovering) which later brought me to make [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50723435/kafka-streams-consumer-groups-concurrency-consuming-from-one-partition-only). After stopping the the KafkaStreams application, I restarted failed brokers, one on a Friday (which took like an hour) and the other one was restarted next Monday.

When brokers joined the cluster apparently OK(showing the "failed, I restarted application.
`__customer_offsets.sh` had replication=3, so they should be safe.

(For reference, cluster situation is better described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50723435/kafka-streams-consumer-groups-concurrency-consuming-from-one-partition-only) ).

My application does some dispatching so the sum of output topics offsets should equal the sum of original events). Whatever does not come there, it goes to an `errors` topic in a catch-all-like fashion, so they always match.

However, when restarting, the application began processing from the beginning, having almost doubled the number of processed messages(when the failures happened, there was some unprocessed lag).

If the `__consumer_offsets` were not lost (and they weren't apparently - they just showed underreplicated but living in the broker that was fine during all the process), why would the application start processing from zero? Under which circumstances is this expected - or may this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka deletes offsets after some retention time -- default is 24h. Thus, if you did not change the config, on restart the broker detects old offsets and deletes them.

Default is increased to 7 days in upcoming 2.0 release: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-186%3A+Increase+offsets+retention+default+to+7+days

Also compare: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-211%3A+Revise+Expiration+Semantics+of+Consumer+Group+Offsets